# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs.urls'

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm working on a Django project from a book right now. The version is a little outdated so I've been trying to follow the documentation for the more up to date version on some things. I'm running into an issue adding the urls. It says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs.urls'
```

My urls.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls'))
]
```

Is there any other code I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `urls.py` in your `learning_logs` app folder AND you have to have `learning_logs` inside `INSTALLED_APPS` in main `settings.py`.